# How can I convert an .abs or .s19 to a C file?

Tags: c

I am trying to run some MC9S12DP256 example files, but I want to see the code to understand it. Are there any ways to convert a .s19 or .abs file to a C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ".s19" or an ".abs" file contains mainly the machine code of the application. The source code of it is not included, independent of the language used to write it. Even if it were written in assembly language, all symbolic informations and comments are excluded.

However, you can try to de-compile the machine code. This is not a trivial or quick task, you need to know the target really well. I did this with software for other processors, it is feasible for code up to some KB.

These are the steps I recommend:

1. Get a disassembler and an assembler for the target processor, optimally from the vendor.
2. Let it disassemble the machine code into assembly source code. You might need to convert the ".s19" file into a binary file, one possible tool for this is "srecord".
3. Assemble the resulting source code again into ".s19" or ".abs", and make sure that it generates the same contents as your original.
4. Insert labels for the reset and interrupt entry points. Start at the reset entry point with your analysis.
5. Read the source code, think about what it does.
6. You will quickly "dive" into subroutines that execute small functions, like reading ADC or sending data. Place a label and replace the numerical value at the call sites with the label.
7. Expect sections of (constant) data mixed with executable code.
8. Repeat often from point 3. If you have a difference, undo your last step and redo it in another way until you produce the same contents.

If you want C source, it is commonly much more difficult. You need a lot of experience how C is compiled into machine code. Be aware that variables or even functions are commonly placed in another sequence than they are declared. If you want to go that route, you usually also have to use the exact version of the compiler used to generate the original machine code.

Be aware that the original might be produced with any other language.